# Insert <p> at the starting of each line and </p> at ending of each line in multi line string of Python using Regular Expression?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to add

at starting of each line and

at ending of each line of python multi line string using Regular Expression. Is there any simple solution for this?

```
import re
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One simple way i got is,

```
body = re.sub("$","</p>",re.sub("^", "<p>", body, flags=re.M),flags=re.M)
```

where sub() is used with "$" means add char

before \n and "^" is to add

at the starting of each line and re.M for MULTILINE.